# os-prober execution has failed

Tags: configuration, grub

Issue on os-prober script

It is failing, hanging at a point it's scanning /dev/sda2
i.e. partiion of ESP, so will grub-mkconfig with enable OS probe option

```
$ os-prober
/dev/sda12:MX 19.4 patito feo (19.4 ):MX:linux
/dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

keep such for 7 minutes

How should repair this (hunch is a imperfection in ESP) ?

Comment: If you're dual-booting with Windows then disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Do that and try again.